# Why is the push button state taking too long to in the program?

Tags: microcontroller, input, pullup, jetson

I wired up the circuit using a pull down resistor of 10KOhm according the schematic provided. I'm using Jetson Nano (MCU).The push button (DF Robot PB) has three wires, +ve,-ve, and signal, pin 1,pin 3 and pin 4 respectively in the schematic.  [image]

The code is shown on the snippet below:[image]

The terminal starts printing 0s when I run the code. If I press the button it immediately changes to 1s. When I release the button it takes a while for the terminal to starts printing 0s again. The button module has an onboard LED that immediately goes off when I release the button. The button is suppose to be momentary push button, but the code behaves a bit differently. Another thing when the state changes from high to low, when I touch the signal wire of the push button it changes immediately and not stay high for too long. I doubt there is anything with wrong with the code or the wiring for that matter. I don't know if it's the length of the jumpers or what, that is causing this behaviour. Or maybe I should add some component that will stabilise the circuit or add something in the code to speed up the process? Any suggestions? Thank you.

`

Comment: The schematic is wrong. According to the schematic, if you push the button, it will short circuit 3.3V supply voltage to ground. Please make sure you know how button is connected, but everything seems to point that there is no pull-down to bring the pin state low, it might simply float.

Comment: Can you provide a datasheet for your "DF Robot PB"?  A normal pushbutton only has two connections and doesn't require a power supply, so I suspect that your button is something more than a simple switch.

Comment: @PeterBennett there is no datasheet in their website. Just a schematic with the red wire connected to Vcc, black wire connected to GND and the green wire connected to the input. I think it has normal push button functionality. It is a small PCB that gives out voltage to the green wire and turn on the onboard LED when the button is pressed. I will try to rewire the the using pullup and then pull down setup. And read up on the debouncing the guys are talking about. Jetson Nano doesn't have those pull up/down resistors on board hence having to use external resistors.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to EE.SE! I would suggest to debounce the button.
[image]

As you can see pressing the button causes the switch to 'bounce' and your MCU will measure unpredictable switch states.

You can use a simple LPF to achieve switch debounce
[image]

Comment: The answer has good suggestions but does not answer the question.

Comment: Debouncing the switch will at least prevent future problems. I agree the button shorts the 3.3V.

Comment: Debouncing has nothing to do with the problem. It might be a loose wire. It still does not answer the question why the push button takes long to read back as low.

Comment: In your schematic the push button only has two wires. The push button that I have has three wires. There is +ve and -ve that always have to be connected. The signal wire is the one that changes state. Is it the signal that is connected to the 1k resistor or +ve?